# How can I add a class definition to a form when I use HTML.BeginForm in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
```

I tried this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "form", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
```

However I don't see the class "form" added. Is there something wrong with the way I am defining it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try defining htmlAttributes parameter explicitly like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-class" })) {
}
```

**Update after reading comment**
Try using one of the BeginForm overloads that allow you to specify route objects (I have not tested this because I dont have an IDE nearby)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-class" })) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. How would I include ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a pain if you want to use the default form, but just add some attributes. [Here is the overloaded method signature that accepts attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505151%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Therefore, you'll need to also supply the action name, controller name, and form method. The first form you have is setting the RouteValueCollection.

What I've done in the past is create my own helper that circumvents the limitation. Here is an example extension method to short circuit all the other parameters.

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace MySite.Extensions {
    public static class HtmlFormExtensions {
        public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes) {
            return htmlHelper.BeginForm(null, null, routeValues, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes);
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to include your namespace in the view (or all views via web.config), then call it like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, new { @class = "form" }))
```